# Jquery image not disable except IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable images at on load, So that it can not be clicked. Below code is working  on IE but not in other browser like firefox,chrome and safari.

```
jQuery('#playersTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('td').each (function() {
        jQuery(this).find('img').each(function () {
            jQuery(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: disabled is not a valid attribute on a img tag .. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**disabled** is not a valid attribute on a **img** tag

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img

best thing to do is just add a class to the images parent .. then when onload, the images you want to not have clicks triggered on will return false due to the check inside the click event handler

```
// add this before page loads
jQuery('#playersTable').addClass('img-disabled');

// returns false if the images parent #playersTable has the img-disabled class 
jQuery('#playersTable').on('click', 'img',function(){

      if(jQuery(this).parents('#playersTable').hasClass('img-disabled')){
          return false;
      }

      // do code stuff

      return false

});
```

then when the page is loaded you can remove the **img-disabled** class

```
jQuery('#playersTable').removeClass('img-disabled');
```

..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another `each()` on `img` tag, try this:

```
jQuery('#playersTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('td').each (function() {
       jQuery(this).find('img').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: my question is the code is not working in different browser like chorme,safari and firefox. Your code do the same what I was doing. I have even tried yours but it not works